# What insights can be derived from the SD of these data?

Tags: mean, interpretation, standard-deviation

I'm a non-Math major. I need help interpreting my students' scores.
The following are the post-test scores of two groups. Group A:
26
32
31
30
36
29
28
29
36
30
36
29
36
38
34
31; Group B: 33
29
37
27
34
28
36
39
32
40
38
36
50
40
32

I computed the mean and standard deviations of the scores and got the following. For Group A: Mean = 31.94; SD = 3.59; for Group B: Mean = 35.44; SD = 5.63. The mean and SD of the two groups' pre-test scores were: Group A: Mean = 17.06, SD =6.29; Group B: Mean = 18.19, SD = 6.39.

I noticed that the mean scores of both groups increased in the post-test while their SD decreased. However, although Group B has a higher mean post-test score, the SD score of Group B is higher than Group A's. What insights can be derived from this? How should I discuss when I present the data?

Answer (score 0):

All you could really say is that "B grades are higher than A post test" and "both groups improved grades after test."

1. The difference in mean grades post test is significant at 5%
2. The difference in means for each group pre- and post-test are significant

On the other hand

- Pre-test difference in mean grades between groups is not significant, if you apply [two way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-way_analysis_of_variance) ANOVA
- The differences in standard deviations is not significant, if you apply ANOVA using the sampling distribution of sample variance. For instance, applying Eq 10 from [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StandardDeviationDistribution.html) would render the standard deviation of the standard deviation for 16 observations as $\approx 0.7$ SD.

Comment: Any insights as to why the SD of the post-test scores of Group B is larger than the SD of Group A's post-test scores?

Comment: @TeacherResearcher, it's not a statistically significant difference, you can still talk to it, of course